# postgres: does where clause filters applied in order they return

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Below is query has 3 filters in where condition, which filter is applied first on table ? does filters applied on table in the order right to left written in query.

I want product_key to be filtered out first and then remaining filters.

```
select *
from order_history
where product_key in (select product_key from products
                      where status = 'avilable' )
  and province = 'Texas'
  and category_key in (3,4,5)
```

Comment: The optimizer decides the order.

Comment: can't we enforce or do we have option to use product_key first bcz i want category_key and province with in those filtered  product_key

Comment: I believe below is one way , we can filter the product_key first
`select *
from order_history h inner join (select product_key from products where status = 'avilable' ) p on h.product_key =p.product_key  where  province = 'Texas'  and category_key in (3,4,5)`

Comment: Trust the optimizer, don't try to fool it. Write simple SQL to make easy to optimize.

Comment: Make sure the statistics is up-to-date.

Comment: You can't tell the planner what the best method is, but I would rewrite the query to avoid subqueries: SELECT *
FROM order_history oh
INNER JOIN products p ON oh. product_key = p.product_key
WHERE p.status = 'avilable' )
  AND oh.province = 'Texas'
  AND oh.category_key IN (3,4,5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which filter is applied first on table ? does filters applied on table in the order right to left written in query.

Since "AND" is transitive, the order has no meaning. This is like saying "1+2" is the same as "2+1". "x=1 and y=2" is equivalent to "y=2 and x=1". This is different from C/C++ where operator && is not transitive: "if( pointer && *pointer )" tests if the pointer is null first, which is what you want, and is completely different from "if( *pointer && pointer )" which will crash if the pointer is null.

The optimizer will try to apply the conditions in the order that it thinks will give best performance. This usually means picking the most selective indexable condition first. For example, if "province='Texas'" only selects 1% of the table, and there is an index on it, then it's a big win to use that first and only apply the rest of the filter conditions to the 1% of rows that passed the first filter. If table statistics are up to date (run VACUUM ANALYZE) the optimizer usually comes up with pretty good choices.

Answer (score 1):

> which filter is applied first on table ?

As stated in a comment, the optimizer determines the order.  It should do so in an informed way -- I would assume the constant comparisons would be before the `in`.  And some of them might be converted to indexes.

You could insist on your own ordering using a `case` expression:

```
select oh.*
from order_history oh
where (case when province is distinct from 'Texas' then false
            when category_key not in (3, 4, 5) then false
            else product_key in (select product_key
                                 from products
                                 where status = 'available'
                                )
       end);
```

I strongly, strongly advise you never to use this approach, because it prevents the optimizer from choosing better execution plans -- for instance, the query won't use indexes or partitions.

However, the `case` expression does evaluate the conditions in order, so you *could* insist on a particular ordering with such a construct.